# Firebase data use unique key to find data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase datd]

I want to use the email to find the "帳號". How can I do it?

THX

Comment: Why can't you replace the `Kof...` data with the email instead if you want that to be your search key?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").orderByChild("put the key of your email")
.equalTo("put here the email you are looking for").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //dataSnapshot includes all the children whose email you wanted
    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        //It will give you what you want
        System.out.println(postSnapshot.getValue("帳號")
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem i recomand you using in stead of that random generated key provided by the `push()` method, the email it self. To check if an email address exists, just use the `exists()` method directly on the `dataSnapshot` object.

Because Firebase does not accept `.` symbol in the key, i suggest you encode the email address like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

Hope it helps.